# How to align the right side of an object to the exact middle of a view SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, constraints, hstack

I have an HStack with two Texts.

```
HStack {
Text("Hello")
Text("World")
}
```

I want Text("Hello") to be on the left side of the page and Text("World") to be on the right side of the page and for both texts to be equidistant from the exact horizontal center of the page. I added a visual for clarification:[Visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gegNT.jpg)

I've tried a bunch of different stuff but I haven't found any way to accomplish this task precisely.

Comment: A one of the grids and push the items to the center with a spacer. Another option is the new Layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the alignment argument of the frame modifier.

Spacing argument for the HStack is for the spacing in between the texts.

```
HStack(spacing: 0) {
    Text("Hello, World!")
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .trailing)
    Text("Hello, World!")
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I really didn't understand your need but according to your drawing I think you need something like below,

```
HStack{
    Spacer()
    Text("Hello")
        .background(Color.orange)
    Spacer().frame(width: 20)
    Text("World")
        .background(Color.orange)
    Spacer()
}
```